# Red Black Tree question

Tags: algorithm, tree, red-black-tree

Can a node in a red black tree have one red and one black child?

I have the following tree, I have specified just the colors here. The leaf nodes are ignored.

```
                   B
           R               B
       B       B       R       R 
     R   R       R
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a node can have differently coloured children. See, for example, the diagram at the very top of [the MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Red-BlackTree.html) on R-B trees; you can verify that it satisfies all the requirements for a R-B tree, and one of its nodes has children of different colours. As, for that matter, does the example you gave.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I ran into this when testing my data structure and wanted to confirm that this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good article on read-black trees in the context of learning data structure in Haskell.

http://scientopia.org/blogs/goodmath/2009/11/30/advanced-haskell-data-structures-red-black-trees/

The R-B tree criteria it gives are pretty clear.  The children of a red node must be black, but a black-node's children aren't specified.  The important point is that all the paths from a given node to to the leaves below it must have the same number of black nodes.  Looking at your tree every path down from the root has 1 black node (2 if you count the root), so it's okay.